# How to integrate Qt library inside Android native project

Tags: android, qt, qt5, shared-libraries

I am a native Android developer, and a client has asked me to re-use his Qt library  project in a native Android app. I am really new to Qt development, I mean, I understand C/C++ but have never dealt with Qt development itself, neither the environment or the deployment methods.

I have been looking into these solutions, but I don't get any closer to being able to create an Android project with a Qt library inside with which I can interact.

Similar solutions:

- http://thebugfreeblog.blogspot.com/2012/05/embedded-cross-platform-development-for.html
- https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/add-native-code#create-sources

My question: How do I export my Qt project to a usable format for my Android project? Any step-by-step guide would be really appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: What kind of library is the Qt library? Note that Qt is designed to run its own event loop, and anything interesting pretty much requires that, as well as a `QCoreApplication` instance existing You should start simple, create a Qt library which, for example, just runs a timer and communicates with your app once per second or whatever. That's not many lines of Qt code. Once you get that integrated, then you can try with a more complex library.

Comment: It's a communication protocol library, it generates frames according to certain parameters and when a received frame is processed it parses the frame and returns a "comprehensible" response/parameters. So, yeah, good point, still need to figure out the setup for the project though. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your Qt application is only used for its logic (not the GUI side), what you need it to:

### Adding JNI to your Qt library for Android

JNI (Java Native Interface) allows creating an interface to link and use native (C++) code from Java. This is used to wrap your C++ code and provide functions visible and usable directly from your Android application

- Install the version of Qt you want for Android using Qt's online installer (a checkbox when choosing the version of Qt you want)
- Create a JNI interface to allow your application and the library to talk. This is covered in that sample: https://developer.android.com/ndk/samples/sample_hellojni. I would probably recommend creating another C++/JNI library acting as a wrapper for your C++/Qt library. That way you don't contaminate the original library with JNI dependencies.

### Integrate your JNI library in your application

Once your have a JNI interface, you have to cross-compile and ship that library with your Android application

- Build your native library from Android Studio (after pointing to your Qt libraries and include dir). Alternatively, you can manually build it from Qt Creator (slightly easier) and import only the resulting `.so`. But that will be painful if your Qt library changes
- Package the library (`.so`), and load it when your application starts. This is also covered in the sample. Once the library is loaded, you will be able to use the JNI functions that you exposed and pass arguments, after some conversion work. Your Android application can also pass a handle to the native library, allowing communication in both ways.

### Notes

- Be careful to the licensing of your project. Cross-compiling Qt for Android will likely switch to its GPLv3 or Commercial license, versus LGPLv3 without Android.
- Qt libraries have to be included in your final pacakge. So they either have to be statically linked against your original library, or dynamically linked, and stored in your APK
- You can leverage Qt JNI classes to make the creation of the interface easier, but that is not required: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qandroidjniobject.html
- Threading can become difficult, as calls to/from JNI have to run from the main thread

I would recommend starting from a working example if you find one, as that whole setup will definitely take some time. I don't know of a complete tutorial covering that, but feel free to share if you find one!

Comment: Wow, thank you, right now it's a lot to process and to try out. Thank you for your answer, it's something I haven't seen documented anywhere for now. I'll let you know if I figure something out!